# Connection to Active Directory in anonymous mode, python

Tags: python, active-directory, ldap, mode, anonymous

I want to connect to Active Directory in anonymous mode. I saw that this can be possible, but I didn't find a solution for this. How can I proceed?

For the moment, I'm connecting to AD using the ldap module and an active account in that AD. I want to connect in anonymous mode to avoid changing the password in the scripts at every 2 months (like the domain request us).

Thanks.